# Removing duplicated numbers in an array

Tags: c, sorting, duplicates

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[8] = {4, 1, 5, 4, 2, 7, 4, 2};
    int i, j, k;
    int len = 8;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < len;)
        {
            if(array[j] == array[i])
            {
                for(k = j; k < len - 1; k++)
                {
                    array[k] = array[k + 1];
                }
                len--;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hi,

Above is the code to remove duplicated numbers in an array, but when compiles and executes, I get 4 1 5 2 7 2--which isn't right because I'm supposed to get 4 1 5 2 7.

It seems that I have a problem with len but couldn't figure out where and what in the code specifically needs to be fixed.

Comment: Then you should do some debugging.

Comment: You are changing *len* in third loop and use it in the first two!

Comment: Thanks to you all for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it is a mistake in indentation, or you miss-copied the code from somewhere ?

anyways to get it run, make this minor changes and it runs (Don't expect an explanation I doubt you don't need it)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[8] = {4, 1, 5, 4, 2, 7, 4, 2};
    int i, j, k;
    int len = 8;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < len;)
        {
            if(array[j] == array[i])
            {
                for(k = j; k < len - 1; k++)
                {
                    array[k] = array[k + 1];
                }
                len--;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }

    } // close the main `for` loop


    // you used to print out after each iteration!
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally didn't realize it was the problem with indentation.